# Laravel updating polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

First of all, if there is a better way than using a polymorphic relation for this then please let me know. I have an appointments table that can have either a contact id or a relation id, depending on what the user selects when creating a new appointment. For this I am using a polymorphic relation, instead of having two seperate `contact_id` and `relation_id` columns.

Also, if there is a better way of doing the below (which I am currently doing in both my store and update methods) then please elaborate me.

```
    if ($request->has('contact_id'))
    {
        Contact::find($request['contact_id'])->appointments()->save($appointment);
    }

    if ($request->has('relation_id'))
    {
        Relation::find($request['relation_id'])->appointments()->save($appointment);
    }
```

The above basically checks if either a contact or relation was selected from one of the dropdowns, and if so, it should add that polymorphic relation to the newly inserted appointment.

But what I am doing in my update method, before I check if a contact_id or relation_id has been specified, is the following:

```
Appointment::where('id', $appointment->id)->update(['relationship_id' => '0', 'relationship_type' => '']);
```

So, I first empty the polymorphic relation, and then check for updates, because a contact or relation is optional. So when someone updates his/her appointment, and removes a at first specified contact or relation, it should be cleared from the database. There has gotta be a better way of going about this, and I know that what I am doing is not the way to go. But I am new to polymorphic relations and just trying to learn more about them. Any info will be appreciated :)